# gWidgets based GUI fine on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: r

I have created a GUI application in R that runs perfectly well on my Linux machine (with `RGtk2`) but when I try to run it on the corporate Windows PC, it miserably fails.

I create my GUI containers with this code

```
# Tabbed Window with two tabs
# each of them with separate panes to manage horizontal vs. vertical
win     <- gwindow( "My Business App" )
nb      <- gnotebook( cont=win )
front   <- gpanedgroup( cont = nb,  # Produce the instruction
            label = "Frontend",  horizontal = FALSE )
    front_check <- ggroup( cont = front )
    front_text  <- ggroup( cont = front,  horizontal = FALSE )
back    <- gpanedgroup( cont = nb, 
            label = "Backend"  )    # Maintain the underlying data
    back_slct   <- ggroup( cont = back )    
    back_edit   <- ggroup( cont = back, horizontal = FALSE )
```

On windows, I only see the container created last (`back_edit`).

I'm running R 2.15.2 on both machines. The output of `sessionInfo()` on the Windows machine:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] tcltk     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods
[8] base

other attached packages:
[1] gWidgetstcltk_0.0-53 digest_0.6.0         gWidgets_0.0-52
```

Am I missing something, or does `gnotebook()` simply not work on Windows?

Comment: Example of `?gnotebook` works for me.

Comment: Not here - I only get the title bar with the minimize / maximize / close buttons, no tabs or labels at all! Is there anything I could check or verify?

Comment: Have you tried expanding the window by dragging the bottom corners?

Comment: The code worked as expected on 2.15.1. Likely it is a sizing issue, as Roman is indicating. If you can resize with the mouse there are a few things to try: 1) when constructing `win` pass in `visible=FALSE`. Then when all components are added, call `visible(win) <- TRUE`. This will compute the minimum size based on all the size requests at the time. Or 2) explicitly set the window size with `size(win) <- c(width, height)`

Comment: @Roman Luštrik: sample code works, I have made a mistake, sincere apologies!  --  @jverzani: The `visible = FAlSE` helps to some extent: I now get all the front and back containers and widgets, but still no notebook tabs (see [here](http://godesberg.homelinux.net/pic29170.gif))

Comment: I'll have to see if it is the newer version of R (I used 2.15.1) or perhaps your gtk version that is giving this issue. For the latter can you see if this works to produce a notebook container: `require(RGtk2);w=gtkWindow();nb=gtkNotebook();w$add(nb);nb$appendPage(gtkButton("button"), gtkLabel("tab"))`

Comment: It's tcltk on Windows that doesn't display the notebook tabs - Gtk2 on Linux works perfectly well

Comment: The problem seems to be the `gpanedgroup()`. If I replace it with a simple `ggroup()` I get the notebook tabs, obviously at the expense of my carefully crafted layout....